How can I specify --add-exports during execution of java
I have jar package complied with java 1.8. Now migrated to java 17. Ksh file contain the java command
/etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0/bin/java  $JAVA_OPTS -DDB_INFO_FILE=$DB_INFO_FILE -DRCFILE=$RCFILE -DSASPATH=/home/config -classpath $CLASSPATH com.myproject.Main 1>/dev/null 2>|$ERR_FILE &

During execution encountering error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.myproject.DefaultFormatter (in unnamed module) cannot access class sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.action to unnamed module

I found reference to use --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
but not sure how to add during java execution

You need to add it to that command line... before com.myproject.Main, and not between options that belong together (e.g. -classpath $CLASSPATH are an option and its value). That said, this is something that you really need to address by using the appropriate APIs instead of accessing internal classes.

Review the usage of formatting. The three backticks need to be in their own line. And why the quote?

Firstly, compile with java 9 or 9+ and export command before jar
/etc/alternatives/jre_17/bin/java  $JAVA_OPTS -DDB_INFO_FILE=$DB_INFO_FILE -DRCFILE=$RCFILE -DSASPATH=/home/config -classpath $CLASSPATH --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED com.myproject.Main 1>/dev/null 2>|$ERR_FILE &

